# Tag synonym: device and devices

Tags: support, stack-overflow, tags, synonym-request

Could we have only one tag, either [device](/questions/tagged/device) or [devices](/questions/tagged/devices) since they're both the same?

Comment: Seems a pretty useless tag to begin with to be honest.

Comment: Approximately 1200 uses.

Comment: That doesn't make it a good tag. [homework] 14k questions, but on its way out.

Answer (score 4):

It doesn't make sense to have both [device](/questions/tagged/device), and [devices](/questions/tagged/devices).

I agree with [@Bart](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/161198/bart) that is a useless tag to have: It is used in different contexts, and it is not giving any information about the question that needs to be immediately visible. I also doubt [device](/questions/tagged/device) is being used to filter questions that are then answered, or reviewed in any way.