# burninate request: device and devices

Tags: discussion, tags, burninate-request

A couple of years ago, someone [suggested](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/152072/tag-synonym-device-and-devices) merging [device](/questions/tagged/device) and [devices](/questions/tagged/devices). Nothing happened, apparently because it seemed obvious that these tags were useless.

But oddly, they remained on the site anyway. They need to be killed with fire.

Comment: Please read http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/226897/how-do-tag-removal-burnination-requests-work and comment.